# Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function while using react hook forms and material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

consider the following block of code:

```
 <TextField name="name" required className='my-2 mx-auto' label="Full Name" variant="standard" style={{ "width": "60%" }} value={name} onChange={(event) => { setName(event.target.value); }} {...register({
            required: "Name is required"
   })} />
```

I have replaced the ref with ...register but I am still getting the error, can someone please help me fix it?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this because `TextField` is not only an `input`.

I think you have to pass `{...register({ required: "Name is required"})}` to the `TextField`'s `input` and to do that, you could use `TextField`'s `inputProps` prop. Something like:

```
 <TextField 
    name="name" 
    required 
    className='my-2 mx-auto' 
    label="Full Name" 
    variant="standard" 
    style={{ "width": "60%" }} 
    value={name} 
    onChange={(event) => { setName(event.target.value); }} 
    inputProps={{...register({required: "Name is required"})}}
 />
```

Comment: I changed it to like you said, but the error is still there.